# Dividing a large model into smaller models in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How can you effectively divide a very large model (800 entities) into several smaller models?

I reverse engineered my existing database into Entity Framework entities. I have already divided my model into 15 smaller models - each has its own DbContext class. The problem is that some entities share relationships between models, so I end up with many "EntityType 'foo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType" errors. For these, I proceed to call modelBuilder.Ignore() which prevents this error from being thrown. I then started getting a different error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The navigation property 'Bar' is not a declared 
property on type 'Foo'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from 
the model and that it is a valid navigation property.
```

But there is a virtual property called Bar (with type Bar) defined in Foo. So I'm sure this is a direct result of calling Ignore().

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Could you combine the context classes into a smaller set of DbContext classes so that all of the relationships are covered and no longer refer to a separate DbContext class?  Even though this may be a bit more complex, you could create a separate classes on top of this to perform your business logic and each class would be using the DbContext internally.

Comment: This would unfortunately make the context classes too large and start-up performance is a concern.